# JOptionPane Swing

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

i am trying to make some dialog window which ll naviagte me through the panel. So i made smth like that. Which is kinda good for me. But i have problem, how do make to rid of the icon and highlighted option?

```
Object[] options = {"one",
        "two"};

int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, "", "select one",
            JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            null);
```

there is setted selected object to null, icon to null. but they dont make any effect. When i added PLAIN_MESSAGE the icon disapeared but i still have highlited one of the buttons and 2nd the buttons are aligned to right,  i need center aligment, help please. :)

Comment: If you don’t like what `JOptionPane` does, make your own panel.

Comment: JOptionPane creates a dialog box which looks and feels like standard dialog boxes of the Look & Feel you're using. If you want something custom, then create your own JDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i still have highlited one of the buttons

This is the default behaviour of a JOptionPane.

Check out [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) for an approach that you may be able to use that will allow you to add your own component to the option pane and place focus on that component.

> the buttons are aligned to right, i need center aligment,

Again this is the default and there is no easy way to change this.

For full customization you will need to create a custom JDialog.